# Display Toast if No data found in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, data-retrieval

I am using Parse.com as my back end storage. I am maintaining some students data like name, Roll Number, Percentage etc. I am searching student's data by selecting Roll number in spinner. Till now it is working fine and able to display name and mobile number in list.

But how to display a Toast if no data found in database for particular Roll number. I am using this code which is giving good results if data found but I am unable to display Toast if no results found.

My code is here:

```
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String result=list.get(position);


            ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost> factory =
                    new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost>() {
                        public ParseQuery<AnywallPost> create() {

                            final ParseQuery<AnywallPost> query = AnywallPost.getQuery();
                            query.include("user");
                            query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                            query.whereEqualTo("RollNumber",result);

                            /*
                            //Added by Tara
                           query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<AnywallPost>() {
                               @Override
                               public void done(List<AnywallPost> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                   if (list.size()!=0){
                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                                   else {
                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                               }
                           }); */


                            return query;
                        }
                    };

            // Set up the query adapter
            postsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<AnywallPost>(SearchStudentList.this, factory) {
                @Override
                public View getItemView(AnywallPost post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                    if (view == null) {
                        view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.listview_item, null);
                    }

                    TextView usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_username_TV);
                    TextView mobileView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_mobile_TV);

                    usernameView.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
                    mobileView.setText(post.getTextMobile());

                    return view;
                }
            };
            // Disable automatic loading when the adapter is attached to a view.
            postsQueryAdapter.setAutoload(false);

            // Disable pagination, we'll manage the query limit ourselves
            postsQueryAdapter.setPaginationEnabled(false);
            ListView postsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_student_LV);
            postsListView.setAdapter(postsQueryAdapter);

            postsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    final AnywallPost item = postsQueryAdapter.getItem(position);
                    selectedPostObjectId = item.getObjectId();



                    String selectedpostMobile = item.getTextMobile();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedpostMobile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And this is my Log cat please check this:

```
      03-22 17:19:15.682  20634-                     
          20644/com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp W/art﹕       
           Suspending all threads took: 328.725ms

      03-22 17:19:15.886  20634-
           20634/com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp        
         D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
      03-22 17:19:15.900  20634-    
          20634/com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp         
           E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp, PID: 20634
java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(ParseQuery.java:272)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(ParseQuery.java:871)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.doInBackground(ParseQuery.java:895)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:930)
        at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.loadObjects(ParseQueryAdapter.java:347)
        at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.loadObjects(ParseQueryAdapter.java:327)
        at com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp.SearchDonorList.doListQuery(SearchDonorList.java:673)
        at com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp.SearchDonorList.onLocationChanged(SearchDonorList.java:633)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
       03-22 17:19:16.087  20634-
        20649/com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp W/art﹕ Suspending  
         all threads took: 7.403ms

        03-22 17:19:16.100  20634-
         20649/com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp I/art﹕ Background 
              sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23032(1037KB) AllocSpace     
        objects, 5(652KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 17MB/19MB, paused 9.673ms             
        total 162.031ms
           03-22 17:19:17.267  20634-
         20649/com.example.avenirlabs_pc1.testblooddonorapp I/art﹕ Background 
      partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 34071(1339KB) AllocSpace       
       objects, 48(2MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 15MB/25MB, paused 2.722ms 
  total 123.637ms
```

Comment: what exactly seems to be the issue?

Comment: Why are you unable to display a `Toast`?

Comment: If not data found for selected Roll number then it has to display en error message or Toast that " no Data Found"

Comment: Again, why are you unable to do that exactly?

Comment: ok, and it's not working? ?

Comment: Just check my code which i have commented in query part. finfInBackground. If i will write that then app crashes.

Comment: Remove comment and show log cat with crash ? may be you get list is null

Comment: Can you please post the crash log for that then?

Comment: posted the log cat in coding part it self

Comment: @Ajay If no results found then i am getting empty list only even though i uncomment code. Thats why i want Toast instead of empty list

Comment: Did you read the error? `This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.`

Comment: @cricket_007 As i am admin to database, so i know there is no data. So i am not going to get data in list.

Comment: If its appropriate logcat than your error relates to network connection ,you are checking list.size()!=0 so i'm asking about data

Comment: @Ajay it is commented one. If i will  uncomment that then app crashes

Comment: The error doesn't refer to server side. The problem looks like it is client side. You have a network request that hasn't finished, and  Android crashes and throws that error.

Comment: @cricket_007 will you please help me out how to do it? and let me tell you the data which i am trying to find out does not exist. So it has to show an error. that is my requirement.

Comment: I can't help without knowing every single place in your code where you connect to Parse. You can try searching the error itself. Most hits are about iOS, but the idea is the same. https://parse.com/questions/why-am-i-getting-a-this-object-has-an-outstanding-network-connection-nsinternalinconsistencyexception

Comment: I searched a lot but did not get appropriate solution.

Comment: And this error doesn't even exist in the code you have shown. Learn to read the logcat. The error happens at `SearchDonorList.doListQuery(SearchDonorList.java:673)`. If you want the correct help, show that code

Comment: @Tara first check log cat at you set your Toast .

Comment: Thanks to every one for quick response. I was trying to add query in adapter , which was wrong. I added commented code in loadObjects method and got the required results.